# How do I determine the collation of the columns in an Sybase ASE database?

Tags: database, collation, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

How do I determine the collation of the columns in a Sybase ASE database?

Additional info: I'm using `DBeaver` and `jTDS` driver to connect to the database.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQL Anywhere? Advantage?)?  assuming `ASE` ... does the output from `sp_helpsort` provide the info you want?  if not, please update the question with more details of what exactly you mean by 'collation of the columns'?

Comment: Hi @markp-fuso , it's an ASE. I've got the database migrated to SQL Server and there I have the column collation as SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS. I wanted to know the equivalent in the sybase DB. I guess it doesn't work in a comparable way?

Comment: that string ... `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` ... is greek to me :-)  in ASE there's a default 'collation' (combo of character set and sort order) and it's at the dataserver level , with the details displayed in the output of `sp_helpsort`; other than that I (still) don't understand what you're looking for ... does `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` equate to some particular combo of character set and sort order (and/or something else)?

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS sorts chars in a specific way, is case-insensitive, and for comparisons of unicode expandable characters it doesn't take the expansion as an equivalent (e.g., Æis not equal to AE in that collation).

Comment: have you looked at the output from `sp_helpsort`?  it should be displaying the character set, the sort order (+ 'nocase' if case insensitive) and also include the alphabet and the precedences of characters (based on the sort order)

Comment: Yes, it has a set of rules that in their whole are more or less equivalent to a SQL column collation. Thank you.